# Development plan tool

Tags: software-development

Every time my company has to deploy some applications we make a deployment plan.
We use excel worksheet for this, where all the tasks are listed, plus all the dependencies (e.g. For application `Alpha` to be deployed application `Beta` and `Delta` must be down - not running.) . Right now we have the excel file as a shared document and every time that some user wants to enter the plan for his/her team's application, must lock the file.

I find the excel way not very productive. Do you have some tool to recommend? 
Requirements :

1. Free for business use. We will be using it for commercial applications.
2. Ease of use. Produce a comprehensive result for the sysadmins that will make all the actions.
3. It can be installed on our machines, either as a web or a native application. We can't have it out there because of the client's security requirements.

Comment: Are you opposed to the use of a [kanban board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_(development)) like [Trello](https://trello.com/)?

Comment: Kanban board wouldn't help us at all. The dependencies would get lost.

Comment: Additionally, Gantt charts would be ineffective because of the types of tasks that have dependencies? It's more of a deployment checklist, above all else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a web app called Agilefant. It is an open source tool for managing agile software development. It has an open source edition that can be found here, 
http://agilefant.com/open-source/

Comment: It's not what I need, but I guess what I need cannot be found and the solution you provided is generic enough. Thnx for your help.

Comment: No problem, happy to help